# deepFace.analyze() do not work in pycharm. but why?

Tags: python

When I call the instruction `DeepFace.analyze()`, the execution crashes with an error.

Below there is the code I produced, and also the error I got.

Thank you in advance

```py
while (cam.isOpened()):
    ret,fram = cam.read()
    gry = cv2.cvtColor(fram, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faceInfo = DeepFace.analyze(img_path=fram, actions=['emotion'])
```

The error I got is this:

```py
C:\Users\Shuvo\PycharmProjects\Emusic\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Shuvo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject7/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Shuvo/PycharmProjects/pythonProject7/main.py", line 31, in <module>
    faceInfo = DeepFace.analyze(img_path=fram, actions=['emotion'])
  File "C:\Users\Shuvo\PycharmProjects\Emusic\lib\site-packages\deepface\DeepFace.py", line 308, in analyze
    functions.initialize_detector(detector_backend = detector_backend)
  File "C:\Users\Shuvo\PycharmProjects\Emusic\lib\site-packages\deepface\commons\functions.py", line 47, in initialize_detector
    face_detector = FaceDetector.build_model(detector_backend)
  File "C:\Users\Shuvo\PycharmProjects\Emusic\lib\site-packages\deepface\detectors\FaceDetector.py", line 20, in build_model
    face_detector = face_detector()
  File "C:\Users\Shuvo\PycharmProjects\Emusic\lib\site-packages\deepface\detectors\MtcnnWrapper.py", line 5, in build_model
    from mtcnn import MTCNN
  File "C:\Users\Shuvo\PycharmProjects\Emusic\lib\site-packages\mtcnn\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
  File "C:\Users\Shuvo\PycharmProjects\Emusic\lib\site-packages\mtcnn\mtcnn.py", line 37, in <module>
    from mtcnn.network.factory import NetworkFactory
  File "C:\Users\Shuvo\PycharmProjects\Emusic\lib\site-packages\mtcnn\network\factory.py", line 26, in <module>
    from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, PReLU, Flatten, Softmax
  File "C:\Users\Shuvo\PycharmProjects\Emusic\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from . import initializers
  File "C:\Users\Shuvo\PycharmProjects\Emusic\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    populate_deserializable_objects()
  File "C:\Users\Shuvo\PycharmProjects\Emusic\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\__init__.py", line 82, in populate_deserializable_objects
    generic_utils.populate_dict_with_module_objects(
AttributeError: module 'keras.utils.generic_utils' has no attribute 'populate_dict_with_module_objects'
[ WARN:1] global C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-vi271kac\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. 
We are here to help, but our time is valuable and so I recommand you 
to take the time for a [mre]. 
The chances to get an answer are much higher than without. 
If you haven't done yet, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 and read [ask]. In addition I suggest to 
[format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your question well, 
and you do can check out all of the points in this 
[checklist](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)

Answer (score 1):

When using deepface, you need to pass an image path to `analyze` in order to work.

Digging down in [the source](https://github.com/serengil/deepface/blob/master/deepface/DeepFace.py#L262) (because no documentation is found), this is the docstring for `img_path`:

> img_path: exact image path, numpy array or base64 encoded image could be passed. If you are going to analyze lots of images, then set this to list. e.g. img_path = ['img1.jpg', 'img2.jpg']

In order to convert the CV2 Image to a Numpy array, you need to execute this code after you get the frame from `cam.read()`:

```py
from PIL import Image  
import numpy as np

image = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
image_np = np.array(image)
```